# Do I need both of these files to generate Excel files, or only one, and which one?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, vba

I need to generate Excel files using C#; I'm using Visual Studio 2013. To acquaint myself with how it's done, I'm working through the tutorial [here](http://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/341-c-sharp).

It says to add a reference for "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library"

I couldn't find it right off, so I got impatient and searched on "Excel 12". I got two results from that search, namely:

```
Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (from MS, version 1.6)
-and
Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel 12.0 Type Library (also from MS, version 12.0)
```

Do I just need the first one (the one mentioned in the tutorial), or is the second one complementary, or does the second one replace/obviate the first one?

vs2013 excel excel12obj vstoolsforoffice designtimeadaptor c#

Comment: Since the first one matches the name exactly, I'd just add that one and see if everything works.

Comment: You only need the first one to use excel through interop.  Check out my answer here about creating excel files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254538/read-excel-file-with-c-sharp/31254936#31254936  also some code here that may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264298/winforms-com-exception-opening-excel-workbook/33264744#33264744

Comment: Thanks, Matthew; I'll czech those out now.